# how to search by single date in ms access database?

Tags: vb.net

i want to search record from ms access database by date. i have stored date in ms access table as "8/23/2020 5:31:21 PM". i am getting syntax error. how can i do this?

```
    Dim x As Date = DateTimePicker1.Value
 
    Dim command As New OleDbCommand("select col1,col2,col3 where table1.datetime = @datetime", connection)

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datetime", x.ToString("mm/dd/yy"))
```

> code suggested by Pete -S-

and its working.

in this i have changed datatype to shortdate in ms access

```
    Dim x As Date = DateTimePicker1.Value
 
    Dim command As New OleDbCommand("select col1,col2,col3 From table1 where ([datetime] >= @startDate And [datetime] <= @endDate)", connection)

     Dim dateParameter As OleDbParameter = command.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@startDate", OleDbType.Date))
     dateParameter.Value = x.Date

     dateParameter =  command.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@endDate", OleDbType.Date))
     dateParameter.Value = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day,1,x.Date)
```

Comment: Argh! Why do people do this? DO NOT store dates as text. There are very few databases that don't have a dedicated data type for dates and times. Access does so you should be using that data type. You can then filter the data by actual dates and/or times instead of text that looks like dates and/or times but has no actual meaning. Store the data properly first, then you can think about querying it properly.

Comment: Moreover it is highly unlikely that you can retrieve a date complete with time and seconds using an equal comparison.

Comment: However your code doesn't even reach the point in which the engine searches your database. It stops at the parsing level of your command text because your sql is missing the FROM clause and _DATETIME_ [is a reserved word in MS-Access](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/learn-about-access-reserved-words-and-symbols-ae9d9ada-3255-4b12-91a9-f855bdd9c5a2?ocmsassetid=ha010030643&correlationid=db60c40e-5b8e-4d91-8c13-a7cb38f0db28&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us#duplicate=0).

Comment: How is your data stored?  Because if it's as a string that's a different solution than if your data is stored as type datetime.  You could be mixing up your types (string vs datetime).  If stored as datetime, you actually want a **range** between midnight of one day and midnight of the next day.  If stored as string, then you might want to use the `LIKE` operator in your SQL statement.

Comment: I am saving it as datetime data type

Comment: @jmcilhinney How can you tell he's storing the date as text in the db?  He's not specifying the data type in `command.Parameters.AddWithValue` ?

Comment: What is the actual error?  As @Steve pinpointed one of your major issues (syntax is not correct) to correct.

Comment: @Pete-S- He is taking a Date from the DateTimePicker and changing it to a string for a parameter value.

Comment: @Mary, Steve pointed that out to me as well (I understand jmchihinney's comment) and I think the reason the .ToString is employed is to remove the time portion from the date picker value, not knowing that the . Date property will do the same thing.   Thanks for the follow up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Steve pointed out the time issue, when searching dates that include time with the date, one solution would be to search the entire range of the day:

**Option 1: table1.datetime >= '8/23/20' And table1.datetime < '8/24/20'**

```
Dim command As New OleDbCommand("select col1,col2,col3 From table1 where ([datetime] >= @startDate And [datetime] < @endDate)", connection)
    
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDate", x.Date)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endDate", DateAdd(DateInterval.Day,1,x.Date))
```

Preferred method of adding parameters, explicitly set the data type when adding the parameter:

```
Dim dateParameter As OleDbParameter = command.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@startDate", OleDbType.Date))
dateParameter.Value = x.Date

dateParameter =  command.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@endDate", OleDbType.Date))
dateParameter.Value = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day,1,x.Date)
```

If `x = 8/23/2020` Then
Your SQL that executes will be `select col1,col2,col3 From table1 where (table1.datetime >= '8/23/20' And table1.datetime < '8/24/20')`

This will include all times on 8/23/2020 between 00:00:00 and 23:59:59... (before the next day).  If you do not specify the time, 00:00:00 is presumed.  That is why equality and time don't play out as you think it should when searching.

**Option 2: table1.datetime >= '8/23/20' And table1.datetime <= '8/23/20 23:59:59'**
Explicitly add the time to the search value.  This will work 99.99% of the time unless there is a value stored that has a time stamp between 23:59.59.0001 and 00:00:00.0000 that could be filtered out.

Comment: If the underlying column in the database is of type DateTime, then do not pass parameter of type string with a format that your database could not understand. Instead just pass the DateTime variable. Also a better choice is to avoid AddWithValue and use the Add method that allows you to specify the parameter type. Still your code doesn't address the DateTime reserved word. You should put square brackets around the word DateTime if you don't want to confuse the parser.

Comment: @Steve I see what you are saying and what jmcilhinney was referring to now.

Comment: @Steve, I've updated the answer to reflect your input, thanks for your input.  I also suspect that the SQL example is pseudo-code due to the column names "col1,col2,col3" and "datetime".  The underlying issue, which you pointed out in your comment was the time and not handling the time in the criteria (that was my goal for my answer).  In any case, I/we should show the best practice so that bad code is not perpetuated.

Comment: i fully appreciate your effort.but after your code insert now it is showing message box message that no data found. it means it is not searching by date. i am saving dates in ms access database with datetime datatype.but when i change [datetime] < @endDate) to [datetime] <= @endDate) and save date with short date your code works.

Comment: @pankajbabbar: there are 2 parameters: `@startDate` and `@endDate`.  The `@startDate` is the beginning of the day: **8/29/2020 00:00:00 (12:00 AM)** and `@endDate` is the next day at midnight, which you want less then (however, not equal to) **8/30/2020 00:00:00**   The where clause should `[datetime] >= @startDate AND [datetime] < @endDate`.  One thing to check, are you assigning the correct value to the parameters?

Comment: @pankajbabbar: if you can, append the code you are using to your original question for everyone to review and give you feedback on.

Comment: respected sir, i have added parameters as per your instructions. i have single datetime column in ms access with datetime datatype and i added parameters very carefully.

Comment: @pankajbabbar can you show us more details, the current code you have, a small sample of the data that is in the column.   Thanks.

Comment: sir, should i add code suggested by you below my question and my error creating code

Comment: @Pete -S- kindly check sir.

Comment: @pankajbabbar: that's fine.  Changing the data type to short date, the data in the column no longer stores the time with the date and now you CAN have an equal search because you no longer need to account for the time.  Good luck with your project, glad we could all help.

Comment: @Pete-S-, I agree with your code in principle but I would tidy it up a bit: `command.Parameters.Add("@startDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = x.Date` and `command.Parameters.Add("@endDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = x.Date.AddDays(1)`.